# Execute file with default program from zsh?

Tags: command-line, zsh

In windows powershell I can open a pdf in adobe reader by doing

```
> Invoke-Item ~/path/to/my.pdf
```

Is there a way to open files in the default gui app from zsh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `xdg-open ~/path/to/file.pdf`.